# list.push_back() not working: throws error C++

Tags: c++, string, list, for-loop, push-back

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

string song = "CDE";
int songlength = song.length();
int counter = 0;

int main() {
    cout << songlength << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < songlength + 1; i++, counter++) {
        list<string> songlist;
        songlist.push_back(song[counter]);
        if (counter <= songlength) {
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner and I do not know much about this programming language.

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)'
```

Comment: You're creating a list of strings, but `song[counter]` returns a character.

Comment: Note: "throw" is not a great word to use in your question title, since `throw` is the C++ keyword for throwing an exception, which happens it run time.  You are getting a *compile time* error, not a *run time* error.

Answer (score 1):

The class `std::string` does not have a constructor with the first parameter of the type `char`.

Either  you need to declare the list like

```
std::list<char> songlist;
```

or like

```
std::list<std::string> songlist;
```

But in the last case you need to call the method `push_back` like

```
songlist.push_back(std::string( 1, song[counter] ) );
```

using the constructor

```
basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Also you need to place the declaration of the list before the for loop. Otherwise within the loop the list is created anew in each iteration of the loop.

For example

```
std::list<char> songlist;
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < songlength; i++ ) {
    songlist.push_back(song[i]);
}

for ( char c : songlist )
{
    std::cout << c;
}
std::cout << '\n';
```